# Round float to 2 decimals javascript but round to down

Tags: javascript, rounding

I need to round a float number in javascript, but I need to round to down in caso of 1.005.
I use the function .toFixed(2) but this round to up. For example

if I have 1.005 and use toFixed(2) The result gives 1.01 but I need 1.00
There is another function to do this?
thanks!

Added

I have this scenarios:

Original number  |  Expected number

25.0010          |   25.00

25.0050          |   25.00

25.0049          |   25.00

25.0051          |   25.01

25.0090          |   25.01

Answer (score 2):

Imho the easiest way to do it is like this: where the 100 represents 2 zeroes, 1000 would be 3 zeroes and forth

```
Math.floor(1.235*100)/100; // Gives you 1.23
```

**Update/Edit:**
..or you can do (since your comment seemed to state you wanted something else then the original question):

```
Math.round(1.009 * 100)/100; // Gives you 1.01
```

Regarding your comment, the "correct" way to round .5 is **up**, meaning that rounding 1.005 to a number with a maximum of 2 decimals gives you 1.01, same as 1.009 gives you 1.01. The other thing you can do is to "cut" away decimals (meaning NO rounding), then 1.005 gives you 1.00, but 1.009 will also give you 1.00.

Comment: but in this case if I have 1.009 this return 1.00 and I need 1.01

Comment: Ah, i thought you meant you did not want it rounded. I am not by my computer right now, but i think you can change that to math.round(SAME NUMBERS AS BEFORE) instead

Comment: Added some to the answer, it is not clear to me what you really want, so i have answered it with two different answers above and you can pick and chose with one gives you want you want. If neither does that then please explain what input you have, and what output you want.

Comment: I add the scenarios to the question

Comment: Hmm the mathematical way to round 0.0050 is up, are you perhaps counting money? That's the only place i know where to round 0.5 downwards, but 0.51 upwards.. i will have to look into this because i do not know if there is a standard function for this.